# Passing New Data to simulate.glmmTMB

Tags: r, regression

In a previous question ([Generate a predicted count distribution from a ZINB model of class glmmTMB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53599574/6365720)) I asked how to generate a predicted count distribution for a zero-inflated negative binomial model of class "glmmTMB". One solution that I have since found to that question is the function simulate.glmmTMB (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/glmmTMB/versions/0.2.3/topics/simulate.glmmTMB). However, I want to do the simulation on test data to validate a model for predictive ability and I only see how to run simulations on the same data used to fit the model.

In the example below, how could I simulate outcomes for the newdata data frame?

```
library(glmmTMB)
data("bioChemists", package = "pscl")
zinb <- glmmTMB(art ~ fem + mar + kid5 + phd + ment, ziformula = ~ ., data = 
bioChemists, family = nbinom2(link = "log"))
sim_1 <- simulate(zinb) #works as expected

#make new dataframe
newdata = unique(bioChemists[,c("fem","mar","kid5","phd","ment")])
sim_2 <- simulate(zinb, newdata = newdata) #ignores newdata
```

Comment: this probably has to be done by hand ...

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, @Ben Bolker. Would that entail something along the lines of this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/14967981/6365720)? I've tried to extrapolate that solution to this case, but had trouble generalizing it to a much more complicated model structure. I'm happy to put the time in to do this by hand but frankly do not know where to begin. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this works (could be encapsulated in a function etc.):

```
n <- nrow(newdata)
## construct model matrices for conditional and Z-I
##  components (.[-2] drops the LHS of the formula)
X <- model.matrix(formula(zinb)[-2],newdata)
X_zi <- model.matrix(formula(zinb,component="cond")[-2],newdata)
## extract coefficients
beta <- fixef(zinb)$cond
beta_zi <- fixef(zinb)$zi
## draw random values for each component
cond <- rnbinom(n, mu=exp(X %*% beta), size=sigma(zinb))
zi <- rbinom(1, prob=plogis(X_zi %*% beta_zi), size=1)
cond*zi
```

The last step is a little too clever: `ifelse(zi==0,0,cond)` might be clearer, or for the last three steps you could use the `rzinbinom` function in the `emdbook` package ...

In general I think `simulate()` methods **should** allow both `newdata` and `newparams` - it opens up a big range of possibilities for parametric bootstrapping, posterior simulation, etc. etc..

---

More compactly (and probably more robustly):

```
cond <- predict(zinb, newdata=newdata, type="conditional")
zi <- predict(zinb, newdata=newdata, type="zprob")
emdbook::rzinbinom(nrow(newdata),
                   mu=cond, size=sigma(zinb),
                   zprob=zi)
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to walk me through this - I really appreciate it. It is also vindicating to hear you agree that `simulate()` should allow `newdata`.

Comment: @benbolker are you aware of a method for this but when you have also have predictors on the dispersion parameter? So the original formula might be something like `glmmTMB(art ~ fem + mar + kid5 + phd + ment, dispformula = ~ fem, ...)`. I can't find a way to extract predictions for the dispersion parameter from the generated model.

Comment: The only way I know to make these predictions is the hard way, i.e. `f <- formula(model, component="disp"); X <- model.matrix(f, data=newdata); beta <- fixef(model)[["disp"]]; eta <- X %*% beta; sd_pred <- exp(eta)`

Comment: @BenBolker how might you implement this solution for an nbinom1 model estimated in glmmTMB?  I'm assuming that the fact that `simulate.glmmTMB()` provides counts for an NB-1 model suggests that some sort of `rnbinom1()`-like function somewhere, but all the simulation pawned off to TMB and C functions in that package, I can't figure out where.